# Plist File cannot be created. iOS+NSDictionary+JSON

Tags: ios, json, nsdictionary, plist

I am having problem with creating the Plist File that saves data received from web service using JSON. The Plist File cannot be created. The path is empty and data is saved to nowhere. This problem occurred when I cleaned the derived data. Please suggest any solution for this.

JSON data:

```
eventID = 2356;
eventName = "Testing Event";
```

This is how I save in Plist:

```
NSArray *eventsDictionary = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"eventList"];
NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:eventsDictionary
                                                              forKey:@"Events"];

if ([eventsDictionary count]==0) {
    NSString *path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:DATA_DICTIONARY_KEY_USER_DEFAULTS];

    [plistDict writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
} 
else {
    NSString *path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)lastObject];
    path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:DATA_DICTIONARY_KEY_USER_DEFAULTS];
    [plistDict writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please post the exact error.

Comment: 1) why is your array variable named `eventsDictionary` instead of `eventsArray`? 2) why do you only save the file if the array is empty?

Comment: @rebello95, there is no error. Plist File Cannot be created. I can't understand why. Even documents folder does not have the plist file.

Comment: I'm assuming `DATA_DICTIONARY_KEY_USER_DEFAULTS` is some invalid path and it therefore can't create it. What is its value?

Comment: @rmaddy, 1) I just named it as eventsDictionary, I don't think that could be the reason. 2) This means if the "eventsDictionary" is empty, save the data.

Comment: if the dictionary/array is empty... there's nothing to save.

Comment: @rmaddy, the value for DATA_DICTIONARY_KEY_USER_DEFAULTS is  "DATA_DICTIONARY.plist". This problem occurred when I cleaned the derived data.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still too confused to help you.

Comment: What kind of object(s) does `eventsDictionary` contain?

Comment: @TomHarrington, it is actually array of dictionaries. EventsDictionary is an array that contains multiple dictionaries. The dictionary contains items with keys and objects such as: eventID = 2356; eventName = "Testing Event"; eventID = 111; eventName= "Testing".  The problem is even Plist File cannot be created. Just NO Plist file. Hope this is clear.

Comment: What kind of "items"? Instances of what classes, specifically?

Comment: @TomHarrington, the items I get from web service using JSON. Then I create: NSDictionary *eventsDictionary = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"eventList"];
NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:eventsDictionary forKey:@"Events"];
NSString *path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:DATA_DICTIONARY_KEY_USER_DEFAULTS];
[plistDict writeToFile:path atomically:YES]; As I know this should save the data into Plist File. ButPlist File is not being created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned in a comment that the data was obtained from a web service as JSON and then converted to a dictionary.

The problem is almost certainly that your JSON data contains null values, which means that your dictionary contains instances of `NSNull`. You cannot write `NSNull` to a file like this because it is not one of the property list types. Writing a file like this only works with instances of `NSDictionary`, `NSArray`, `NSString`, `NSData`, `NSNumber`, and `NSDate`. Also any dictionary keys must be strings.

If there's an `NSNull` (or an instance of any non-property list class) then writing the file like this will fail.

You need to either go through the data and remove all `NSNull` instances, or else write your file some other way.

Comment: that's right. But it is very strange as it saved with null values before. Anyway, thank you very much, sir :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest way: 
Add your dict to array:

```
NSMutableArray * mutArr = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[mutArr addObject:plistDict];
[self saveToPlistName:@"yourplist" fromArray:mutArr];
```

and use this method

```
-(void)saveToPlistName:(NSString *)plistName fromArray:(NSMutableArray*)array
{
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentFolder = [path objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentFolder stringByAppendingFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@.plist",plistName]];
    [array writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"SAVE SUCCESS TO DIRECTORY%@",filePath);

}
```

vote for me if its helpful for you

Comment: still there is no Plist File.